# To start a sentence about yourself in a 3rd person with "Been..."?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Usually people when talking about themselves say something like: "I've been a tutor since 2010". But it's said in a 1st person.
My question is... Would it be correct to describe yourself in a 3rd person like so: "Been a tutor since 2010"? To start a sentence with "been"...?

Comment: If I wanted to write about myself in the 3rd person, I would begin such a sentence with _Has been..._

Comment: @KateBunting - +1 But you don’t seem like a has-been to me....

Comment: So when writing about yourself there're 3 options. 1) To use just nouns; 2) To use your own name as a subject ("John has been a tutor..."); 3) To omit the subject so it would be like "Has been a tutor...". All three ways are correct?

Comment: The difference between your first quoted sentence and your second is not a change from first person to third, but merely an elision. (Not only is the subject pronoun dropped, but the present perfect verb is reduced to a bare participle, which cannot manifest either first or third person.)